# What's the difference between key=len, key=lambda x: (len(x), x)) in python3

Tags: python, sorting

I was trying to sort the list by element's length and if the length is same sorting by lexicographical order.
test list is:

```
test = ['abcd', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dbca', 'bcda', 'ssdfgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdef']
```

And, i tried two ways of sorting.

One is key = len

```
test1 = sorted(test, key = len)
```

The other is key = lambda x : (len(x), x)

```
test2= sorted(test, key = lambda x : (len(x), x))
```

They show different results.

test1's result is:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'abcd', 'dbca', 'bcda', 'ssdfgh', 'abcdef', 'abcdefgh']
```

test2's result is:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'abcd', 'bcda', 'dbca', 'abcdef', 'ssdfgh', 'abcdefgh']
```

I want to know how they work differently. How can I find the internal structures in sorted(key = ~)? In python docs, it just explains how to use. I want to know internal code. How it is structured, not how it is used.

Comment: Because ``len`` is equivalent to ``lambda x: len(x)`` but not ``lambda x: (len(x), x)``? I mean, why do you think they *should not* have different result, seeing how they are different code?

Comment: First version sorts by length only, second version sorts by length first, and lexicographic order second if two strings have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `key = len` sorts by length ***only***
- `key = lambda x : (len(x), x)` sorts by length first and when length is the same it sorts lexicographically

that's why the first test leaves the part `'dbca', 'bcda'` as is

while the second test reorders that to `'bcda', 'dbca'`

Comment: How can i study the internal structure's difference between key = len and key = lambda x: (len(x), x)) ? I want to know the detail. why they work differently.

Comment: `len` sorts [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) while `(len(x), x)` sorts [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (in your case the tuple of a number and a string)

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and unambiguous explanations.